# Show function f, with first derivative continuous, can be represented as the difference of two nondecreasing functions.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Show that if f existing in [a, b], then f can be represented as the difference of two nondecreasing functions on [a, b].

I  know that any f of bounded variation can be expressed as the difference of two monotone increasing functions on [a,b] and thus can be expressed by the difference of two nondecreasing function on [a,b].

But how can it be shown otherwise? Or with the use of integration?

Answer (score 2):

Define $f'^{+}(x) = \max \{0, f'(x) \}$ and $f'^{-}(x) = \min \{0, f'(x) \}$. Then, we have $f'(x) = f'^{+}(x) + f'^{-}(x) = f'^{+}(x) -  (-f'^{-}(x))$. Then,
$f(x) = F_1(x)- F_2(x),$ where $F_1'(x)= f'^{+}(x) $ and $F_2'(x)= -f'^{-}(x).$ $F_1$ is nondecreasing. Similarly, $F_2$ is also nondecreasing

Comment: Minor correction: $f(x)=F_1(x)-F_2(x)+C$ where $C$ is a constant, but $C$ can be absorbed in $F_1$.